# Retroactive annulment of conversion?

Tags: conversion-to-judaism, children-parenting, baby-infant

If a woman converts to Judaism, has a baby, and then converts to Christianity, is the baby still considered a born Jew? That is, can the woman's conversion be retroactively annulled in a way that affects her children?

Comment: Your question should be, if a convert to Judaism changes his mind about it after the fact, is the conversion annulled?

Comment: @JenniferLuttes Welcome to Mi.Yodeya and thanks for your question.

Comment: The edited version of this question now appears to be closely related to, or possibly a duplicate of, ["Can conversion be revoked?"](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/50602)